# How to draw various tangent circles in a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw the following picture:

[image]

But, I can only draw a part of it.

[image]

My codes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
    \foreach \i in {0,60,...,330}{
        \draw (\i:3.4) circle (1.7);
    }
    \draw (0,0) circle (5.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How to complete the figure?

Comment: You only need to compute the coordinates for the remaining 3 centers and radius. Then, repeat the process with another `\foreach`.

Comment: Please format your code when you ask questions. You've been around for long enough that people should not have to routinely do this for you. But every time you ask a question, somebody else has to format your code. Personally, I'd consider it rather rude to keep expecting people to do this for me. (I'm not saying you are being rude - only that, were I to do it, I'd consider myself rude.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The three small circles can be used to calculate the line segment CF in dependency from the small radius *r*:

   > CF = *r*/cos(30)
2. Triangle BCE can be used to calculate CE with radius *R* of the larger circles:

   > CE = sqrt(3) *R*
3. Triangle BFE can be used to calculate EF (Pythagoras) in dependency from the smaller radius:

   > EF = sqrt(*r*² + 2*Rr*)
4. Now, CF can be calculated using 2. and 3.:

   > CF = CE - EF
5. Then, the equation

   > CF (from 1.) = CF (from 4.)
   >   calculates the smaller radius.

The following example uses 1 as larger radius without option `scale`. Then the smaller radius is

> 9 - 6 sqrt(2)

Example file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\radius{9-6*sqrt(2)}
  \draw
    \foreach \i in {0,60,...,300} {
      (\i:2) circle (1)
    }
    \foreach \i in {90, 210, 330} {
      (\i:{\radius/cos(30)}) circle (\radius)
    }
    (0,0) circle (3)
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Heiko Oberdiek - Excellent. Thanks for your patience and generosity